# Eclipse RCP application - create Preference page entry, which is saved encrypted

Tags: java, encryption, eclipse-plugin, preferences, rcp

I found a possibility to create preference pages for my Eclipse 3.7 RCP application. 
How to do that is described [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html#preferencepage).

**Question:** 
Is it possible to add an entry field to the preferecne-page, which will be saved **encrypted**, in a Secure storage?

Until now I only found a way to use Secure storage programmatically. 
This is not a solution for me, because the preference-page entries are saved automatically.

**SOLUTION:**
I did, what Tonny Madsen said to:

- extended the `SecureIPreferenceStore` class, which is an `IPreferenceStore`.
- made the new class store all preferences in a secure storage by using a private variable of type `ISecurePreferences`
- set the new class as the PreferenceStore for the preference page

*Extension of ScopedPreferenceStore*

```
public class SecureIPreferenceStore extends ScopedPreferenceStore {
```

/* Current class will override all storage and loading methods, using this secure preferenceStore, to store all preferences in an encrypted way. */ 
    private static final ISecurePreferences SECURE_PREFERENCES = SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault();

/**
* Use this class to retrieve an instance of  {@code SecureIPreferenceStore}, which will store all preferences in the default secure storage.
 * 
 * @param context - the scope to store to, e.g. {@link org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.ConfigurationScope ConfigurationScope} 
 * or {@link org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.InstanceScope InstanceScope}
 * 
* @param qualifier - the qualifier to look up the preference node. An example of a qualifier would be the plug-in identifier that the preference is associated with,
* (e.g. the "org.eclipse.core.resources" uses the preference node in the instance scope where the preferences for "org.eclipse.core.resources" are stored)
*/
public SecureIPreferenceStore(IScopeContext context, String qualifier){
        super(context, qualifier);
}

@Override
public void setValue(String name, boolean value) {
    try {
        SECURE_PREFERENCES.putBoolean(name, value, true);
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void setValue(String name, double value) {
    try {
        SECURE_PREFERENCES.putDouble(name, value, true);
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void setValue(String name, float value) {
    try {
        SECURE_PREFERENCES.putFloat(name, value, true);
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void setValue(String name, int value) {
    try {
        SECURE_PREFERENCES.putInt(name, value, true);
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void setValue(String name, long value) {
    try {
        SECURE_PREFERENCES.putLong(name, value, true);
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void setValue(String name, String value) {
    try {
        SECURE_PREFERENCES.put(name, value, true);
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean getBoolean(String name) {
    Boolean result = false;
    try {
        result = SECURE_PREFERENCES.getBoolean(name, result);
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public double getDouble(String name) {
    Double result = 0.0;
    try {
        result = SECURE_PREFERENCES.getDouble(name, result);
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public float getFloat(String name) {
    Float result = 0.0f;
    try {
        result = SECURE_PREFERENCES.getFloat(name, result);
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public int getInt(String name) {
    int result = 0;
    try {
        result = SECURE_PREFERENCES.getInt(name, result);
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public long getLong(String name) {
    Long result = 0L;
    try {
        result = SECURE_PREFERENCES.getLong(name, result);
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
}

*Usage of the new Class in the FieldEditorPreferencePage:*

```
    @Override
    public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
        setPreferenceStore(
                new SecureIPreferenceStore(ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE, 
                        "de.vogella.rcp.preferences.secure") );
        setDescription("A demonstration of a preference page implementation");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but...

I would add my own `IPreferenceStore` for the secure storage and then use the usual `FieldEditors` in preference pages.

The easiest way to do this, is to sub-class `ScopedPreferenceStore` overriding `getStorePreferences()` to return a new `IEclipsePreferences`. This is likely a sub-class of `EclipsePreferences` overriding the various `internal...(...)` methods to interface to `ISecurePreferences`. Given the fact that the internal methods pretty much match the methods of `ISecurePreferences`, this will probably not be extremely difficult :-)